# Excel - concatenate from reference columns 2 across entire table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set that looks like this:

161   169   181   193   241   253   238   238

165   173   181   191   253   271   232   238

And I'd like to reference the data set in a new table that concatenates 2 neighboring columns across all of the columns of the reference table without repeating a column. The output would hopefully look like this:

161169   181193   241253   238238

165173   181191   253271   232238

What equation in excel can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try **Index** function.

Such as the data number is A2:H2, then we can find the odd and even columns via `=INDEX($A2:$H2,1,COLUMN(A2)*2-1)&INDEX($A2:$H2,1,COLUMN(A2)*2)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following formulas:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1</kbd>

```
=BYCOL(WRAPCOLS(A1:H1,2),LAMBDA(α, CONCAT(α)))
```

---

Formula needs to fill down!.

---

Also if one is using `MS365` and presently in `Beta Channel` then one could try the following formulas as well! `BYCOL()` with `CONCAT()` but without `LAMBDA()` construct.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1</kbd>

```
=BYCOL(WRAPCOLS(A1:H1,2),CONCAT)
```

---

Or, Using **[GROUPBY()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/groupby-function-5e08ae8c-6800-4b72-b623-c41773611505)** if in `MS365 Beta Channel`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1</kbd>

```
=GROUPBY(,WRAPCOLS(A1:H1,2),CONCAT)
```

---

Or, with one single dynamic array formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1</kbd>

```
=WRAPROWS(BYROW(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:H2),2),CONCAT),4)
```

---